# How to start win32 service via Python

Tags: python, pywin32

I have to run my python script as win32 service as following:

## aservice.py

```
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32api
import win32con
import win32event
import win32evtlogutil
import os

class aservice(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
   
   _svc_name_ = "aservice"
   _svc_display_name_ = "a service - it does nothing"
   _svc_description_ = "Tests Python service framework by receiving and echoing messages over a named pipe"
         
   def __init__(self, args):
           win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
           self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)           

   def SvcStop(self):
           self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
           win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)                    
         
   def SvcDoRun(self):
      import servicemanager      
      servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,(self._svc_name_, '')) 
      
      self.timeout = 3000
      from cron.realtimemonitorschedule import startMonitor
      startMonitor()
      while 1:
         # Wait for service stop signal, if I timeout, loop again
         rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
         # Check to see if self.hWaitStop happened
         if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            # Stop signal encountered
            servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("aservice - STOPPED")
            break
         else:
            servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("aservice - is alive and well")   
               
      
def ctrlHandler(ctrlType):
   return True
                  
if __name__ == '__main__':   
   win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrlHandler, True)   
   win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(aservice)
```

I could install the service successfully, but when i start the service,it will prompt error as following:

```
from cron.realtimemonitorschedule import startMonitor
ImportError: No module named cron.realtimemonitorschedule
```

Note that cron.realtimemonitorschedule is defined in realtimemonitorschedule.py, my question is that how could i call my script from the win32 service? I could not embed my script in the above aservice.py

Comment: where is cron.realtimemonitorschedule installed in your environment?

Comment: @ ciphor, to be shamed, i'm new to Python. I did not know how to install cron.realtimemonitorschedule in ENV so that win32 service could find it:(

Comment: so, could you run the python script in command line?

Comment: @ ciphor, yes.I could run from Eclipse via PyDev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to figure it out, i need to let Python find my modules.Either by set the path to PYTHONPATH or just copy the whole modules to PYTHON_HOME folder, the later is for test only.